# Как вернуть response от Retrofit в onResume()

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Имеется метод, который отображает список репозиториев конкретного юзера:

```
private fun serverConnect(){
    obj = object :Callback<List<GitHubPOJO>>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<GitHubPOJO>>, response: Response<List<GitHubPOJO>>) {
            responseSave = response.body()!!
            posts.addAll(responseSave)
            mRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            response.body()?.forEach { println("TAG_: $it") }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<GitHubPOJO>>, t: Throwable) {

        }
    }
    retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/") // CHANGE API
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
    service = retrofit.create(GitHubService::class.java)
    repos = service.retrieveRepositories(name)
    repos.enqueue(obj)
}
```

Список является кликабельным. Как мне передать ответ от сервера в onResume, что бы список оставался кликабельным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашлось само. Может кому-то пригодиться.
Вот мой код onResume:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    repos?.clone()?.enqueue(obj)
    recyclerClick()
}
```

recyclerClick() - метод с onClickListener для recyclerView